# Angular SubViews/Multi-region templating, Directives and Dynamic Template URL

Tags: templates, view, angularjs, routes

I'm trying to set up a page with two "view areas", one with the standard ng-view that the framework automatically handles, and a custom view area to have another part of the page change-out with the change in view. I figured I could/should do this with directives, but I'm pretty new to Angular and having trouble getting it to work.

So, for example if I have:

```
<body>
    <div class="fixed-menu">
        <nav>this never changes</nav>
        <fixed-menu-view></fixed-menu-view> <!-- this need to change with ng-view -->
    </div>
    <div class="content" ng-view> <!-- this changes with an update to the location/routeProvider -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The ng-view is already handled by Angular, but I need a segmented template with another part of the page updated as well, so I'm trying this but not sure how to pass in the routeProvider to get the current "page".

```
directive('fixedMenuView', function () {
    // Can't seem to pass in $scope or $routeProvider here
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: //computed from the current scope or routeprovider url,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    }

});
```

Is there a better way to do this, or what can I do here to accomplish what I'm trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `route` service into the directive through dependency injection. This is also how you are able to inject any other additional services etc.

There is a little more information in the docs, but unfortunately not too many decent examples: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Once injected, you can access the current route with `$route.current`: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route)

```
directive('fixedMenuView', ['$route', function ($route) {
    // Can't seem to pass in $scope or $routeProvider here
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: //computed from the current scope or routeprovider url,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Do something with $route.current here
        }
    }
});
```

In your case, I would create a 'shell' template for the directive, with either switches inside depending on the current route, or possibly `ng-include`, if you have a large number of routes to accommodate etc.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find the right DI keyword to put in the signature (I was trying $routeProvider like in app.js). Unfortunately $route.current is undefined, so two steps forward, one step back. :) Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah, you may need to put something like `scope.$watch($route.current, function(...))`.. This will update the directive on each `digest` cycle, the link function is only run once when the directive is being created... at which point data isn't bound, and is probably undefined etc.

Comment: Great info @AlexOsborn. With 1.2. the ngRoute is a separate module, the link to the documentation updated accordingly is: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to use event message instead of the route parsing for two reasons:

1. you are making a dependency with your url.
2. you will be able to only display the information defined in the URL

I suggest another solution based on event. First define some event listeners in your navigation bar controller:

```
$scope.$on('logout', function() {
    $scope.setLoggedOutBar();
});
$scope.$on('login', function() {
    $scope.setLoggedInBar();
});
$scope.$on('changeSelectedApp', function() {
    $scope.changeSelectedApp(myContextService.getSelectedApp());
});
```

Then in your nested view controller you can spread the event:

```
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        myContextService.setSelectedApp('main');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('changeSelectedApp');
    });
```

One of the benefit of this solution is that other components can catch the event and update their contents.

Comment: This seems to be a more flexible solution that can also be applied to different problems. +1